# Which topoi are local with respect to Stone-Cech compactification?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory, stone-cech-compactification

Compact Hausdorff spaces $X$ are characterized among all topological spaces by the fact that for any topological space $S$, the embedding $S \to \beta S$ into its Stone-Cech compactification induces a bijection $Map(\beta S, X) \to Map(S,X)$. I'm wondering which topoi $\mathcal X$ enjoy a similar property.

I'm not sure there is an agreed-upon definition of "compact Hausdorff topos", but at least for localic topoi, there's an agreed-upon definition of what it means to be compact Hausdorff, and an applicable notion of Stone-Cech compactification due to [Banaschewski and Mulvey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.588.9841) (sorry for the non-doi link, I can't seem to find a doi).

**Question:** For which Grothendieck topoi $\mathcal X$ is it the case that for every localic topos $\mathcal S$, the geometric morphism $\mathcal S \to \beta \mathcal S$ induces an equivalence of groupoids $Geom(\beta \mathcal S, \mathcal X) \to Geom(\mathcal S,\mathcal X)$?

Here $Geom(-,-)$ denotes the (large) groupoid of geometric morphisms.

I'm particularly curious if this holds for all coherent topoi $\mathcal X$ (but as Simon Henry points out in the comments, it obviously fails for $\mathcal X = Set[O]$, the object classifier, which is coherent). A topos $\mathcal X$ enjoying this property would likely be a topos which I'd be happy to call a "compact Hausdorff" topos (quite apart from considerations of properness of certain geometric morphisms). If the answer changes when a smaller class of localic topoi $\mathcal S$ is considered, I'd be interested to hear about that too.

Bonus points for a characterization which also works in infinity-topoi.

Comment: Nice question ! Do we know what this condition means for the case of $\mathcal{X} = BG$, the topos of $G$-sets with $G$ a discrete group ?

Comment: Ok, I would suggest to change a bit the question, maybe replacing discrete sets by boolean locales, because as such the notion is actually poorly behaved: every topos without points is "compact Haussdorf" in your sense for trivial reasons. (And so yes: it can change dramatically by looking at more general class of spaces than discrete sets).

Comment: Maybe I might as well go all the way -- the largest class of topoi for which I know there's a well-defined notion of "Stone-Cech compactification" is the class of localic topoi. Maybe I should ask for $Geom(Sh(\beta L), \mathcal X) \to Geom(Sh(L),\mathcal X)$ to be an equivalence for every locale $L$. In the original formulation, I'm additionally worried because if $X$ is a topological space and is local with respect to $S \to \beta S$ for all discrete $S$, then I can show $X$ is compact and $T_0$, but I can't actually show that $X$ is Hausdorff!

Comment: I know that the Gleason cover of a topos shows that every topos has "enough Boolean-valued points", but does every topos have enough "boolean localic points"?

Comment: Yes. every topos admit an open surjection from a locale, whose Gleason cover is a boolean locale.

Comment: Additional remark: That property do not holds for all coherent topos: Take S[O] the "object classifier" (the classyfing topos of the theory with one sort and no axiom). Then your property would mean that $Sh(S) \simeq Sh(\beta S)$ which is obviously false. My best guess so far  is that the topos you considered (once you replace S by all locales or all boolean locales) are exactly the ones that are "compact Haussdorff" in the sense that $X \to 1$, $X \to X \times X$ and the second diagonal $X \to X \times_{X\times X} X$ are all proper geometric morphisms.